# Write a 2-d array in a for-loop

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I want to create 2 arrays from the following for-loop:

```
with open('y.txt', 'w') as f:
    for j in range (1, 3):
        xN = 0.5 + 0.5*random.uniform(0, 1)
        r = 3.8 + 0.15*random.uniform(0, 1)
        for i in range (1, 313+1):
            xNew = logistic_map(xN, r)
            xN = xNew
            f.write("%f" % xNew)
```

This is of course creating a text file of 313*2=626 rows.
What I want to do is to be able to automatically create *j* arrays:

Q(*j* = 1) = the first 313 points
Q(...)
Q(*j* = *N*) = the last 313 points.

Also, how do I save this to a text file, with 313 rows and *j* columns? The text file I have now just saves a file with 626 rows.

Answer (score 0):

To create a 2D array, you can modify your code like so:

```
import numpy as np
Q = []

for j in range (1, 3):
    xN = 0.5 + 0.5*random.uniform(0, 1)
    r = 3.8 + 0.15*random.uniform(0, 1)
    temp = []
    for i in range (1, 313+1):
        xNew = logistic_map(xN, r)
        xN = xNew
        temp.append(xNew)
    Q.append(xNew) # Saves each row of 313 points as a separate sub-array

 Q = np.transpose(np.array(Q)) # Convert this to an array and take the transpose of it
```

Then you can use [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save this as a text file.

However, if you don't actually need the sub-arrays to contain 313 points, you can add the points in the transpose order directly, thereby skipping the later `np.transpose()` step. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
Q = [[0 for j in range(2)] for i in range (313)] # Creates an array of zeros with 2 columns and 313 rows

for j in range (1, 3):
    xN = 0.5 + 0.5*random.uniform(0, 1)
    r = 3.8 + 0.15*random.uniform(0, 1)
    for i in range (1, 313+1):
        xNew = logistic_map(xN, r)
        xN = xNew
        Q[i][j] = xNew

 Q = np.array(Q) # Convert this to an array and take the transpose of it
```